# Google Cloud Storage Java not storing file to storage space

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I have followed below link to upload/create a file to my bucket in Google cloud storage.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/#Java_Using_Google_Cloud_Storage

When I run my application locally it is not throwing any kind of exception but it's not even uploading file to storage space or not creating any file to Google cloud storage.

But when I visit

localhost:99/_ah/admin

It's showing a row added in "*GsFileInfo*" Entity.

Why it is not uploading file to remote side at cloud storage space?
What I need to update to do so?

Answer (score 4):

The local development server runs entirely locally.  It simulates the production environment on your local machine for the purpose of testing.  In your case, it simulates GCS behavior on your local machine, it doesn't actually save to GCS.

If you want to actually save to GCS, you need to deploy your app and run your saving procedure on production App Engine.

Comment: I have managed to work the same. I am running my application locally and uploading files to GCS through client's browser. I will share the solution soon.